# jquery cookie doesn't work on localhost even in firefox

Tags: html, django, firefox, cookies, localhost

Actually problem already described in title) Few moments:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static "jquery.cookie.js" %}">
    </script>
```

But in console of Chrome/Firefox - $.cookie is not defined

```
    $.cookie
    undefined
```

Thanx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code for the `jquery.cookie.js` file, you spelled scr instead of src. Correct line would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "jquery.cookie.js" %}">
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, please check that the `{% static %}` tag actually outputs a valid URL (just copy the URL from there and try it out in the browser).

Comment: Also make sure you are not importing `jquery` again somewhere below the `jquery.cookie.js` line. This happens surprisingly often ... Having another `jquery` import will overwrite the reference for the original `jquery`, the one that `jquery.cookie` registered to

Comment: I have import of jquery for bootstrap at the end of template. Now I remove it. But...it's still doesn't work. I add screenshot http://prntscr.com/9dia9k with Watch. I think it's not good that $ and jQuery active = 0. I wish i could fix it. but i'm newbie in JS

Comment: @nurekil the `scr` typo is still there. Can you please post a `plunker` or something so I can see the entire generated HTML?

Comment: you was right - I "spelled scr instead of src". I thought that if I had miswrite debugger would say it. 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```